# How to make flex items fit their content when wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with the property flex-warp set to wrap.
When the elements break into multiple lines they leave extra space in their last position.
How do I remove the extra space (marked with red lines in picture below) ?

[image: extra space marked with red lines]

What I want to achieve here is a paragraph of text with 2 buttons in front of it, and the 2 buttons should respond to the paragraph's width => when there is one line of text, the buttons should be  positioned horizontally, else they should be positioned vertically.

```
 .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        max-width: 500px;
    }

.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
  align-content: start;
}


<div class='container'>
    <p class='content-text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, consectetur.</p>
    <div class='controls'>
        <button class='edit-btn' title='Edit'>A</button>
        <button class='delete-btn' title='Remove'>B</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqvrzxam/13/

Comment: Why not just remove `flex-wrap` on `.controls`? Or give `.controls` a larger `flex-basis`?

Comment: @Dai : "What I want to achieve here is a paragraph of text with 2 buttons in front of it, and the 2 buttons should respond to the paragraph's width => when there is one line of text, the buttons should be positioned horizontally, else they should be positioned vertically."

Comment: What you're asking is impossible: CSS has no way of changing other elements' properties based on how many line-breaks or wrapped lines are in a different element's DOM `#text` node (and no, the `:first-line` psuedo-class selector won't help you here). You _can_ likely approximate this behaviour with `flex-basis` as I suggested, but it won't be _perfect_.

Comment: When there is two lines of text the width of the paragraph changes, and that's why the flex-wrap works. The problem here is the extra space left.

Comment: You're only considering the case when the `<p>` contains sufficient text such that it has to wrap. You're not considering a `<p>` with a short line caused by a `<br />`, for example.

Comment: The `<p>` will contain text only (no html).